# Implementing SHORTCUT

Tags: android, android-widget, shortcut, homescreen

i want to implement SHORTCUT  as we see in android emulator. i want to know how to get the long clicked grid item on homeScreen with same position/co-ordinates as that of menuScreen. atleast provide me some ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? It isn't completely clear to me...

Comment: I want the idea of: when i long click on any app in android emulator's menuscreen, the app icon and app text expands and gets positioned in homescreen at the same place as they were in menuscreen... like an app which is first in menuscreen, will appear first in homescreen's gridview...